# Semantic-UI range date

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

In form validation is possible check a range date??

```
'person-born-date': {
                    identifier  : 'person-born-date',
                    rules: [{
                            type   : 'date[01/01/1900...new Date()]',
                            prompt : 'Invalid date'
                    }]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at html5 native input type date. Consider to use min and max attribute.

Comment: I found a good solution, on custom functions:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1708